# How to compare the lenghts of lists in lists efficiently?

Tags: python, loops

I have 2 lists a and b which contain sublists that have different lenghts, and i want to find a sublist in a and a sublist in b that have the same length.
My approach was:

```
for j in range(0, len(a)-1):
    for k in range(0, len(b)-1):
        if len(a[j]) == len(b[k]):
```

Problem being that a and b can both contain around 150 elements, and those loops are also in a for loop which can run this clutter about 400 times.
Is there a more effecient way to do it?

I tried the code I provided and it still hasnt finished running as of writing this question.

Comment: Yes, you can find all lengths of both, sort them, then compare with linear complexity.

Comment: Small but important point: you can just use `range(len(a))` to go through all indices within a. As of now, you stop one index too early.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do it would be to find the lengths first. This would reduce the nested lists to normal lists, then it is much easier to find the common element.

```
a2 = map(len,a)
b2 = map(len,b)
```

From here it is much simpler, one way to do it is using sets:

```
set(a2).intersection(b2)
```

This would return all intersections between the two lists. From here it is trivial to find the sublists with the specified lengths in the two lists.

Comment: As long as you don't need to find if the sublists are identical, this is a **great** and elegant answer

Answer (score 2):

If the indices are the same size, I would sort each of the lists by the length of each sublist and go from there.

```
a.sort(key=len)
b.sort(key=len)

for item in zip(a,b):
    sublist_a,sublist_b = item
    if len(sublist_a) == len(sublist_b):
        return sublist_a #or whatever you need
```

If the sizes of `a` and `b` are *not* the same, then still sort but iterate through the larger of the two and keep track of the relevant index

Comment: Sadly like I mentioned are the indicies not the same but thank you so much for giving me a rough idea how to do it

Comment: Wow my bad - didn't read it as well as I should have